# How to perform additional action on login in Laravel 5.8?

Tags: laravel

In Laravel 5.8 the Auth\LoginController is just:

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/my-team';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

On login I want to perform some custom actions for the user, but I can't figure out where I can place this code. The documentation doesn't seem to help.

Is there a method I can overwrite/extend with my own?

Laravel 5.2 used to have a `login()` method in the `Auth` controller where I could just write additional code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `login()` method in LoginController. As you said, in Laravel 5.8 the `login()` method doesn't exist, but you can define it yourself. The newly defined `login()` method will override the default one and then you can do whatever extra you want to after or before the user signs in. Here is a snippet from Laracasts:

```php
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateLogin($request);

        if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
        }

        if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password, 'is_activated' => 1])) {
            // return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        }  else {
            $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
            return response()->json([
                'error' => 'This account is not activated.'
            ], 401);
        }

        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
    }
```

Just go through it and see what has been done there. In short, you can modify the `login()` method to do whatever you want before or after a user signs in.

Comment: the login methods does exist , it's in the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait

Comment: @DerDjamel but you can't modify `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers` as it will get overwritten.

Comment: I am not talking about whether you can overwrite it or no, I am talking about whether it exist or not

Comment: @DerDjamel The OP tried to find `login()` method in `LoginController` so the solution is to define the login method as it isn't defined in `LoginController`. Yes it does exist in `AuthenticatedUsers` but he shouldn't be modifying that file. For this reason, I suggested to override the `login()` method and that's the standard way to achieve what he wants :) And you are right as well in some context.

Answer (score 1):

There are two functions provided by the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait. You can customize those in the login controller.

**Login Form**

```
public function showLoginForm()
{
    return view('auth.login');
}
```

**Handle Login**

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateLogin($request);

    // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
    // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
    // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
    if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
    }

    if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
        return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
    }

    // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
    // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
    // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
    $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

    return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}
```

You can place these two functions in the login controller and make changes as you want.

Answer (score 1):

The best place to add your custom actions is to override `authenticated` method in your `LoginController`

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    // Your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go to where the `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers` trait is located and you will find all the methods you want 
it's located in :

```
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers
```

Or you can overwrite it in the LoginController to do what ever you want